# WordPress HTTPS on all but 1 page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, https

I've found a few similar posts here but I've not been able to make those solutions work.

So I have a site that I want to be serving through HTTPS except one page domain.com/property-listings/

This page needs to be HTTP due to a 3rd party iframe we must have on the site that serves via http.

Here is my current htaccess file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```